# How to move the commandline cursor on bash using the mouse

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, inputrc

When using bash (in Terminal) with very long commands, it is often useful to be able to set the cursor to an arbitrary location using the mouse. In Mac-Os, the alt (Option) key is having this effect (use alt+click).

I started using Linux, and this option does not work. I believe there is some way to update the ~/.inputrc that enables this option. Do you know of such a way?

Comment: Here's a link which might help you http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35021/how-to-configure-the-terminal-so-that-a-mouse-click-will-move-the-cursor-to-the
And don't spam all places asking the same question again & again.

Comment: I was explicitly advised in Stack Overflow (where the question was originally posted), to move the post here. Since the original question became on hold, posting it here was the natural course of action, not spamming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bash` (and the `readline` library) does not handle mouse events.

As far as I know, Mac OS's Terminal.app works it around  by emitting a certain amount of Left or Right keypresses upon such an Alt + mouse click, according to the location of the cursor vs. the location of the click. I don't know how Terminal.app detects whether it's safe to do so, and I'm afraid it makes a lot of false positives in other apps (when it sends tons of arrow keypresses that don't make sense in the given context).

My best recommendation is to get used to Ctrl + Left or Right which move the cursor word by word.

Answer (score 5):

Bash supports `Ctrl+x, Ctrl+e` shortcut  which opens current command line in default editor (or editor specified by EDITOR env variable), e.g. VIM  and lets you use mouse to jump across the line being edited.

Once you quit VIM, the command will be executed. Which one extactly, depends on how you quit.  To quit and save changes use `ZZ` from normal mode. Use `ZQ` to abandon changes.

To enter `insert` mode use `i`, to return to `normal`  use `Esc` or `Ctrl+c`.

To turn enable mouse in VIM permanently, use `:set mouse=a` in the`.vimrc` file.
For nano, see [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1033710/529734). Shortly, put `set mouse` in `~/.nanorc`.

Works in bash on linux. Maybe works on macs too. I hope this helps.

Comment: Not quite completely correct. What editor is opened depends on the OS and configuration. By default on Debian Buster (v10) for example, ctrl-e opens the command line in `nano`.

Comment: Thank you, @JulianKnight, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The terminal [rxvt-unicode](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rxvt-unicode) moves the cursor to the mouse position with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Left Click</kbd>.

This will behave exactly the same at <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Left Click</kbd> does in the Mac terminal.